# can we have two application in one servlet project?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

The background for this question is that I am trying to use sendRedirect from one Servlet to another.

so if we can't have two application in one servlet project. then, i will have to put both these servlet in two different Servlet project. If I do so, will sendRedirect work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are wanting to serve up multiple roots under a single application you sure can.  Using servlets it would look something like using the pre 3.0 spec

```
<servlet>
   <servlet-name>servlet1</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>com.test.servlets.Servlet1</servlet-class>      
</servlet>
<servlet>
   <servlet-name>servlet2</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>com.test.servlets.TemplateServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>servlet1</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/api/servlet1/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>servlet2</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/api/servlet1/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

So if your WAR is called TestApplication.war you'd get to the servlets by going to

```
http://localhost:8080/TestApplication/api/servlet1/MorePath?also=variables&go=here
http://localhost:8080/TestApplication/api/servlet2/MorePath?also=variables&go=here
```

You could put a fitler in the web.xml that could either do a redirect from one serlvet to the other depending on your business rules, or you could transparently forward the request to either servlet through the servlet dispatcher which you can get by request.getServletContext().getNamedDispatcher("servlet1")